# Citation appears within pipes not brackets

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, citing

When citing within the text, the citation appears within lines like so: |1| instead of within brackets like so: [1]. Within the bibliography, the citations appear correct. I have a hunch that there is a problem with the display, making the citations look like it's between lines because the serifs aren't displaying properly, but I can't figure out the problem.

Here is the preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bibtotoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} %1,5-facher Zeilenabstand
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\restylefloat{table}
\graphicspath{{Bilder/}}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{LiteraturBericht3.bib}
\newcommand{\chapterref}[1]{Kapitel~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\sectionref}[1]{Abschnitt~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\subsectionref}[1]{Unterabschnitt~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\equationref}[1]{Gl.~(\ref{#1})}
\newcommand{\figureref}[1]{Figur~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\tableref}[1]{Tabelle~\ref{#1}}
\def\SymbReg{\textsuperscript{\textregistered}}

\usepackage[breaklinks,pdfpagelabels,pdfstartview = FitH,bookmarksopen = true,bookmarksnumbered = true, colorlinks = false, urlbordercolor = {white}, linkbordercolor = {white}, citebordercolor = {white}, plainpages = false, hypertexnames = false, citecolor = black] {hyperref}

\usepackage[automark, headsepline, autooneside=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark{chapter}
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\chead{}
\cfoot[]{}
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{scrheadings}
```

And here are pictures of what I mean:
The citation within the text:
[image]
The citation within the bibliography, how I also would prefer them within the text, with square brackets:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same effect can be reproduced in the following smaller document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[
  urlbordercolor = {white},
  linkbordercolor = {white},
  citebordercolor = {white},
  citecolor = black
]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: weird looking square brackets around citation]

The problem is your `hyperref` setup, which adds a white border around clickable links. Since the citation is a link, you get a white borer around the number, which overlaps the surrounding square brackets (on screen).

The effect is visible more clearly if you just load `hyperref` as

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

where you get a green link border overlapping the square bracket

[image: green link border overlapping the square brackets]

If you do not want to visually distinguish clickable links from other bits of the text, you may want to use the `hidelinks` option

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}

\usepackage[
  hidelinks
]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: nicely printed square brackets]

---

In your larger document, you could replace

```
\usepackage[breaklinks,pdfpagelabels,pdfstartview = FitH,bookmarksopen = true,bookmarksnumbered = true, colorlinks = false, urlbordercolor = {white}, linkbordercolor = {white}, citebordercolor = {white}, plainpages = false, hypertexnames = false, citecolor = black] {hyperref}
```

with

```
\usepackage[
  hidelinks,
  pdfstartview = FitH,
  bookmarksopen = true, bookmarksnumbered = true,
  hypertexnames = false,
]{hyperref}
```

(where we replaced the white borders with the `hidelinks` option and dropped options that are the default to make things slightly easier to digest).